# My android activity is freezing and working slow. I need to make it stable

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am trying to create a chat activity, that works with Azure SQL database. Logic is that all messages are listed on a listView, an instance service will check for it if there is a new data on messages table at Database, if there is, it clears ChatAdapter and add all data, then setAdapter to listView again.

When i open the activity, it works, i can send messages, it directly goes on database and comes to screen but activity works slow,spikey and sometimes freezing for half second. Maybe if i do the Database checking in intentservice, it can solve the problem but i don't want to do anything without advices.

I am hardly amateur so my code seems like a mess. Also i "must" solve this problem with this logic. So need advices like " don't do this task here, do it there. Don't use InstanceService, use AsyncTask... " instead of " Use chat services, mobile services, don't do it with Database...." etc.

There is my listView refresh code:

```
public static boolean refreshList()
    {
    if(chatArrayAdapter!=null) {

        chatArrayAdapter.Reset();
        chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      
        listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Mes = null;
    }

    try {


        SqlCon.httpIslemleri(); /** AsyncTask to connect Db**/
        Connection con = SqlCon.returnCon(); /** Returns DB Connection **/
        Statement getMes = con.createStatement();
        SetUser User = Intro.stUser;
        Mes = null;

        Mes = getMes.executeQuery("select * from tb_ms where (ms_sender =  "+User.getid()+" or ms_sender = "+value+") and (ms_getter = "+User.getid()+" or ms_getter =  "+value+")");
        while(Mes.next())
        {
            if(Mes.getInt("ms_sender")==User.getid())
            {
                side=false;
            }
            else if(Mes.getInt("ms_getter")==User.getid())
            {
                side=true;
            }
            chatArrayAdapter.add(new ChatMessage(side, Mes.getString("ms_mes")));
            con.close();

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;

}
```

CheckMesChanges function. That checks if Messages Table changed :

```
public static boolean CheckMesChanges(ResultSet Mes)
{
    SqlCon.httpIslemleri();
    Connection con = SqlCon.returnCon();
    Statement getMes = null;
    try {
        getMes = con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SetUser User = Intro.stUser;


    try {
        MesCheck = getMes.executeQuery("select * from tb_ms where (ms_sender =  "+User.getid()+" or ms_sender = "+value+") and (ms_getter = "+User.getid()+" or ms_getter =  "+value+")");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(MesCheck==Mes)
    {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and my Intent Service that controls CheckMesChanges and calls refreshList if it returns true:

```
public class IntentMesControl extends IntentService {

public IntentMesControl(String name) {
    super(name);
}
final Handler handler = new Handler();


protected void onHandleIntent() {

    if(ChatBubbleActivity.CheckMesChanges(ChatBubbleActivity.Mes)==true)
    {
        ChatBubbleActivity.refreshList();

    }
    else {
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            onHandleIntent();

        }
    }, 500);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {

    if(ChatBubbleActivity.CheckMesChanges(ChatBubbleActivity.Mes)==true)
    {
        ChatBubbleActivity.refreshList();
    }
    else {
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            onHandleIntent();

        }
    }, 500);

}
}
```

I start IntentMesControl at onCreate of activity. So can you help me, give me some advices to make my activity more stable and fast? Thank you.

Comment: It's not a good practice to directly call a method like `Activity.myMethod()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution just for others who can encounter with same problem:

Every Asynctask that connects to your database will take a little time to establish a connection. Also any services that uses activity functions take a little time to. So when you call this Asynctask too many times, it freezes your activity.

Solution is that, if you want to create an SQL Connection, check data and refresh listviews you need to create:

- An IntentService that will connect to database, get data and check for it and returns data if data is changed.
- A function that doesn't connects to your database but gets data and refreshes your list.

So by this way, your connection and data check will be working on background and when data changed, asynctask will call function to refresh list.

It solved my problem. New codes are like that if anybody wants to use.

Function to refresh listView:

```
public static boolean refreshList2(ResultSet Mes2)
{
    if(chatArrayAdapter!=null) {

        chatArrayAdapter.Reset();
        chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        /*listView.setAdapter(null);*/
        listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    SetUser User = Intro.stUser;

    try{
        while(Mes2.next())
        {
            if(Mes2.getInt("ms_sender")==User.getid())
            {
                side=true;
            }
            else if(Mes2.getInt("ms_getter")==User.getid())
            {
                side=false;
            }
            chatArrayAdapter.add(new ChatMessage(side, Mes2.getString("ms_mes")));




        }
        Mes3 = Mes2;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return true;

}
}
```

Intent Service to connect DB and check data is it's changed:

```
public class IntentMesServicev2 extends IntentService {

public IntentMesServicev2(String name) {
    super(name);
}

final Handler handler = new Handler();
Connection con;


ResultSet Mes;
SetUser User = Intro.stUser;
int value = ChatBubbleActivity.value;
public void onCreate (){
    httpIslemleri();
}


protected void onHandleIntent() {

    httpIslemleri();


    try {


        Statement state = con.createStatement();

        Mes = state.executeQuery("select * from tb_mes where (ms_sender =  " + User.getid() + " or ms_sender = " + value + ") and (ms_getter = " + User.getid() + " or ms_getter =  " + value + ")");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Mes != ChatBubbleActivity.Mes3) {
        ChatBubbleActivity.refreshList2(Mes);

    } else {
    }


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {


            onHandleIntent();


        }
    }, 500);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
    httpIslemleri();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {


            onHandleIntent();


        }
    }, 500);

}

public void httpIslemleri() {

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        try {
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("Your DB String");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

It's not freezin now but still this code is a mess and with some little touch, it can work better. Good coding!!

Comment: With regards to the code being a mess. You may want to look at [this article](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/)

Comment: Thank you. I will check this with extra attention.